# Rounded inner border within a table

Tags: html, css, border, html-table, border-layout

I have a fairly complex HTML table structure in which I need to make the inner-top corners rounded as shown in the image below:

[image: Rounded inner table corners]

For the sake of simplicity, the actual HTML for section 2 is fairly complex, but 1 is simply one `td` tag within one `tr` tag.

What styles do I have to apply to get rounded inner corners for the top two corners of the table?

Thank you.

Comment: Set table to border-collapse: collapse; and then set border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px ;

Comment: use tabels only for tables, not for layout. Place the table in a div and add the rounded corners to the div

Comment: Using tables for layout is so 1990's ;)

Comment: @LuisP.A. why are you putting your answer in a comment instead of answer?  Just curious...